# what does the {0} in this line, double [] array = new double[] {0} , do in java?

Tags: java

I want to know what will happen to the array using this.

double [] array = new double[] {0}

does it initialize an array that all of its elements are zero? and if so what will the length of the array be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Note that since the default value for a `double` is already zero, this code is exactly equivalent to `new double[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It initializes the array with the first and only element being 0

Answer (score 0):

The given line initializes a double array. There are 2 ways to initialize an array: new double[arrayLength] or new double[]{arrayContents}. The given code uses the second solution, so it creates a new double array with a single number (which is 0).